# A question for a matrix equality.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $A,B$ be matrices, their entries are real numbers. If $A,B$
are square matrices with the same orders then 
$$
\det\left(A^{T}BA\right)=\det\left(B\right)\left(\det\left(A\right)^{2}\right).
$$
My question is, if their orders are not the same but $B$ is still
square, do we have a formula in the form like this 
$$
\det\left(A^{T}BA\right)=\det\left(B\right)\times\ldots,
$$
here $\ldots$ is something that is interseting enough.

Comment: For example, A is 3x2; B is 3x3.

Answer (score 0):

No,See that determinant is always defined for Square matrices only , in your example even though the final outcome for $A^{T}BA$ may be a square mtrix and of course we can calculate its determinant but we cannot write them as individual factors as $A$ is not a square matrix here.

Comment: I know we cannot have det(A) but may be something else.

Comment: Ok, since finally determinants are numbers you can decompose the determinant of $A^{T}BA$ into factors and you can write them as determinants of some other matrix [matching of corresponding factors] by trial method ! .

Answer (score 0):

No this formula works only for i × j where i = j.

And both A and B are of same order i × j.